# Compare two Timestamps from different Tables

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g

I would like to compare to Timestamps from different tables. I want to get all rows where the stamp from tbl_1 is bigger than the MAX(stamp) from tbl_2.

```
select *
from tbl_1
where timestamp > (select MAX(TIMESTAMP) from tbl_2);
```

unfortunatelly this is not working. I'm always getting zero results :/. Datatype of both colums is date/time

---

OK I found the problem.

The Problem is that if tbl_2 is empty and has no dates, it wont return anything. It works though when I enter a smaller date.

Comment: are you sure that you have rows that satisfy that condition?

Comment: It looks OK to me http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!4/43458/2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Answering the question from the author's answer...

You can use `NVL` to take into account the possibility of the subquery returning NULL (when `tbl_2` is empty):

```
select *
  from tbl_1
where timestamp > NVL((select MAX(TIMESTAMP) from tbl_2), timestamp - 1);
```

Answer (score 1):

I find doing a manual comparison helps.  Run your query

```
select MAX(TIMESTAMP) from tbl_2
```

and see if the date in it is a date bigger than any date you have in tbl_1

```
select MAX(TIMESTAMP) from tbl_1
```

If so that explains why you aren't getting an results and you will have to look at those large timestamps to determine if the records need changed.

To get this to work to return all rows even when you are returning NULL for the MAX(TIMESTAMP) query in tbl_2

```
select *
from tbl_1
where timestamp > (select MAX(TIMESTAMP) from tbl_2) or (select MAX(TIMESTAMP) from tbl_2) is null;
```